# how to change width of uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, subview

I am adding a uitableview cell in as a subview to a UIView thats is also a subview to the ViewController view. but for some reason the UITableViewCell still stretches 320 pixels across  the screen when I initialize it to something much smaller.

Even if I make the view its sub viewed into small it still stays 320 pixels wide. I am wondering if its a Hierarchy problem? I feel like my code is correct but maybe I am just missing something small...

```
//..
 // This UIView holds both custom UITableViewCell and UIButton and is placed at the top of the current UIView
    cellContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 44.0)];
    cellContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    // Select all UITableViewCell
    selectAllCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 7.0)];
    selectAllCell.textLabel.text = @"Select all"; // Set text
//    selectAllCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    selectAllCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // set bg color

    // Create non visible UIButton that sits over customTableviwecell wich allows you to set a selctor on the button press
    UIButton *selectAllButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 50.0)];
    [selectAllButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectAll:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Add custom Cell and UIButton to cellContainer view
    [cellContainer addSubview:selectAllCell];
    [cellContainer insertSubview:selectAllButton aboveSubview:selectAllCell];
    // Ass cellContainer to self.view
    [self.view insertSubview:cellContainer atIndex:1];
//..
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to directly change the width of a `UITableViewCell`: they will take up the width of the `UITableView`, and by default the table view will take up the entire width of the screen. The only way to make a cell smaller in width is to make the table view itself smaller by changing its frame width.

Comment: dag nag it! this is so painful.. do you think apple would frown at me for shifting the cell over to the left so it sits slightly out of view then just move the cell title over to the right.

Comment: Can't say for sure. Apple is notoriously strict about their interface guidelines. From what it sounds like, you're using a grouped table style, as that's the only cell type where its borders are visible (plain table types only show the top and bottom borders). My hunch is that so long as all of the cell borders are visible, they won't care too much about what code you use to make them smaller.

Comment: okay then how about this question, can you have section headers with out the section slider on the right of the UITableView